# Как отсортированную карту записать в txt файл(сейчас просто в консоль выводится)

Tags: java, java-hashmap, hashmap, filewriter

Сортировка карты:

```
map.entrySet().stream()
                    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder())) .limit(10).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Пусть до txt:

```
C:\java\out.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дам ответ [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14906458/output-console-into-text-file-java)

1. Вы можете перенаправить stdout в файл при запуске программы

   ```
   java AccountTest >> test.txt
   ```
2. Вы можете переопределить stdout в программе

   ```
   PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("test.txt", true));
   final PrintStream oldStdout = System.out;
   System.setOut(out);
   // делаем что хотим
   ....
   // возвращаем обратно
   System.setOut(oldStdout);
   ```
3. Вы можете использовать java.io.PrintWriter замене основному System.out

   ```
   PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("test.txt", true));
   out.printf( "account1 balance: $%.2f\n", account1.getBalance() );
   ```

Comment: вот во втором способе куда указать чтобы передавалась отсортированная map именно?

Comment: @beartree Изменил ответ чтобы могли пользоваться там где нужно